# Eclipse Java Program to read non English characters from System.in

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, command-line-arguments, hindi

I am running a simple java program which accepts a line from System.in and splits it for spaces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word="",type="";
    while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
      System.out.println("Enter word");
      String devnagri = sc.nextLine();
      String [] devnagriSpilt = devnagri.split(" ");
    }
```

But whenever I give input in Devanagari script (Sctipt for Hindi and Marathi languages) it gets garbage characters.
e.g. If I give input as   एक दोन तीन चार
Then is retrieved in variable devnagri as  à¤�à¤• à¤¦à¥‹à¤¨ à¤¤à¥€à¤¨ à¤šà¤¾à¤°

I have changed the property of java file and project named "Text file encoding" as UTF-8. Still it does not help.
Is there any other Eclipse setting or JVM argument that needs to be setup ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I give -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 on the command line. I don't know if that setting in Eclipse yields such a JVM argument or if you need to supply the JVM argument as part of the run config.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

1. `Windows` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Content Types`,

   set `UTF-8` as the default encoding for all content types.
2. `Windows` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Workspace`,

   set `"Text file encoding"` to `"Other : UTF-8"`.